# MySQL LEFTJOIN not working

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

This SQL script not working though I don't see any issue in syntax or in join logic.
Could someone tell me is thr something wrong in this SQL?

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM POS_TRANSACTION N1 
LEFT JOIN POS_TRANSACTION T1 ON N1.TRANSACTION_ID = T1.TRANSACTION_ID 
LEFT JOIN MASTER_TABLE1 T2 ON T1.CUSTOM_FIELD6 = T2.TXT_FIELD2 
WHERE T1.TRANSACTION_DATE > T2.DATE_FIELD1 AND T1.TRANSACTION_DATE < T2.DATE_FIELD2 
AND T1.TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN "2013-01-01" AND "2016-07-31" 
AND T2.TXT_FIELD2 IS NOT NULL AND T1.TRANSACTION_ID IS NULL
```

Here, POS_TRANSACTION have millions of POS data and MASTER_TABLE1 ..MASTER_TABLE-N tables(without Primary Keys in it) have master data used to filter pos data.

Agenda: select non-matching POS records from POS_TRANSACTION using selection filter criteria given for POS_TRANSACTION. And I'm not looking for SUB query or Temp table queries.

Note: This SQL working without T1.TRANSACTION_ID IS NULL at the end or with T1.TRANSACTION_ID IS NOT NULL at the end

Comment: Move the condition on the "outer joined" tables from the `where` clause into the `on` clause.

Comment: what kind you error you getting, if you can paste error here

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Query with conditions in ON clause returning full COUNT of POS_TRANSACTION. is Something wrong in the query!?

Comment: How should I know if something is wrong with the query? You don't tell us how your tables look like. You don't tell us what the intention behind the query is. You don't tell us what you expect it to return. You don't show us any sample data.

Comment: Sory! ..Post updated for you

Comment: T2 is joined to T1, but if there is no T1 for an N1 record then T1.TRANSACTION_ID will be null and T2.TXT_FIELD2 will also be null. Can T1.TRANSACTION_ID be legitimately NULL when a T1 record exists?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM POS_TRANSACTION N1 
LEFT JOIN POS_TRANSACTION T1 ON N1.TRANSACTION_ID = T1.TRANSACTION_ID 
LEFT JOIN MASTER_TABLE1 T2 ON T1.CUSTOM_FIELD6 = T2.TXT_FIELD2 
AND T1.TRANSACTION_DATE > T2.DATE_FIELD1 AND T1.TRANSACTION_DATE < T2.DATE_FIELD2 
AND T1.TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN "2013-01-01" AND "2016-07-31" 
AND T2.TXT_FIELD2 IS NOT NULL AND T1.TRANSACTION_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: you removed the where?

Comment: @Mike: he moved the condition from the where to the on clause (where it should be to work correctly in an outer join)

Comment: first join need not to be `left join` since it's joining to the same table. it can just a `join` (self join)

Comment: @Madhivanan/@a_horse_with_no_name, This query returning full COUNT of POS_TRANSACTION. is Something wrong in the query!?

Answer (score 0):

By specifying `T1.TRANSACTION_ID IS NULL` when the join condition is `N1.TRANSACTION_ID = T1.TRANSACTION_ID`, you're effectively asking for all N1 rows that don't have a matching T1 row.  But since you're joining on TRANSACTION_ID, every N1 row must match itself, so is automatically excluded from this criterion.

Therefore, no POS_TRANSACTION can ever fulfil this criterion; and this query will always return no rows.

Comment: How to resolve this? Could you tell me alternative way?

Comment: No I can't.  Because you haven't clearly said what you're trying to achieve.  All you've done is post some SQL, which logically should return no rows, and asked why it returns no rows.  But you haven't specified what you DO want your SQL to return.  If you can tell me exactly what you want in your result set, I'll be able to write some SQL for you.

Comment: You haven't updated your post since my last comment.